# clone jhipster project : SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode

Tags: jhipster

I have forked the last version 3.0 of Jhipster.

I did then :

> sudo npm link
>    yo jhipster

as stated here https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#-generator-development-setup

and got this error :

```
/home/myUbuntu/dev/workspace/generator-jhipster-master/generators/app/index.js:15  
const constants = require('../generator-constants'),  
^^^^^  
SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.  
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)  
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)  
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)  
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)  
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)  
    at require (module.js:380:17)  
    at Object._storeAsPath.Object.defineProperty.get [as jhipster:app]   (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-  environment/lib/store.js:40:23)
    at Store.get (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/store.js:64:35)  
    at Environment.get (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:260:16)  
    at Environment.create (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:292:24)
```

There must be something that I have done wrong, but I can't see what.
If anyone has an idea...

thank you.

I have tried to add an entity :

> yo jhipster:entity car

and got this error :

```
events.js:154
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'endsWith' of undefined
    at Generator.getAngularAppName (/home/myUbuntu/dev/workspace/generator-jhipster-master/generators/generator-base.js:1223:67)
    at module.exports.EntityGenerator.extend.initializing.getConfig (/home/myUbuntu/dev/workspace/generator-jhipster-master/generators/entity/index.js:116:40)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/myUbuntu/dev/workspace/generator-jhipster-master/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/base.js:436:25)
    at /home/myUbuntu/dev/workspace/generator-jhipster-master/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/run-async/index.js:24:25
    at /home/myUbuntu/dev/workspace/generator-jhipster-master/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/base.js:448:8
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:383:17)
```

Comment: Try 'npm install' in generator-jhipster-master and if it does not work, please indicate your nodejs version.

Comment: That was a problem of node version. thanks.

Comment: Great, could you tell us which version so that maybe we can adjust our package.json

Comment: nodejs -v gives me : 0.10.25,

Comment: Ok, so far we have 0.12 as minimal version in package.json

Comment: I updated to 0.12. added an entity and got an error (see main edited main post), related to nodejs version?

Comment: No it looks like you have run 'yo jhipster:entity car' in a different directory than the one where you have generated your app. If that's not case, please open a new question and add your .yo-rc.json file, I have added an answer to the orginal question so we can close it.

Answer (score 2):

You must use NodeJS 0.12.x at minimum.

Answer (score 0):

This help me !

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_5.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```